# "I trenta denari": si tratta di un modo di dire?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, idioms

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> Un giorno il babbo, stretto dal bisogno, si era rivolto al tuo protettore per avere trecento lire. Erano molte trecento lire, allora. Al babbo servivano per comperarsi una marsina usata da un rigattiere, siccome aveva trovato lavoro al «Gambrinus» dove i camerieri portavano le falde. Il babbo, faceva il cameriere nei caffè. Con le poche decine di lire che rimasero, la famiglia si concesse una scampagnata. Furono **i trenta denari**. Da quel giorno il babbo non rimise piede a Villa Rossa. Ora il tuo protettore era sicuro di averti conquistato definitivamente; all’ironia di sua moglie si aggiunse un argomento di più.

Immagino che l'espressione "i trenta denari" faccia riferimento al tradimento di Giuda, quindi il senso in questo contesto sia che, chiedendo questo prestito, il padre in certo modo vende il figlio a "suo prottettore". Tuttavia mi chiedo se questa espressione, "i trenta denari", sia una sorta di modo di dire o frase fatta. Se è così, potreste farmi qualche esempio di uso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il  riferimento a Giuda è stato ampiamente illustrato. Ecco alcuni esempi di uso comune in cui l'espressione "trenta danari" viene usata come modo di dire in riferimento a soldi mal spesi o mal guadagnati.

Da [*Aspro e Dolce*](https://books.google.it/books?id=BRfBcDIrt8MC&pg=PA62&dq=%22trenta%20denari%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0kpyu0rnZAhVLtRQKHX3pBY8Q6AEITTAH#v=onepage&q=%22trenta%20denari%22&f=false) di Maurizio Corona

> Ma così non fu. Un manipolo di resistenti trovò il coraggio di tenere duro, di opporsi agli urtoni dell'arroganza, e non abbandonare il luogo natio, o cederlo per trenta denari a gente che neppure oggi, dopo quarant'anni a smesso di mirare allo sfruttamento del nostro torrente.

Da [*Se mi innamorassi di te*](https://books.google.it/books?id=dYYXAAAAMAAJ&q=%22trenta%20denari%22&dq=%22trenta%20denari%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz3YL707nZAhUKXhQKHQ6-Bts4ChDoAQguMAI) di Oreste Del Buono:

> « Ecco... » ansimò lei. « Non c'è neppure necessità che tu aumenti l'offerta... Non me lo merito... nei trenta denari è compreso tutto... e magari ci starei anche senza... senza i trenta denari... puoi risparmiare... Tienteli, i tuoi trenta denari.

Da [*Letterature moderne*](https://books.google.it/books?id=7V4YEilGIicC&q=%22trenta%20denari%22&dq=%22trenta%20denari%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-m9_81LnZAhWKWBQKHdQRCl4Q6AEITzAJ), Malfasi:

> E allora si risolve: bravamente, affronta lo spettro, eli propone il mercato: e lo spettro gli offre trenta denari. Ladro, lo chiama Pierrot, ma è costretto, accetta, gli dà l'abito.

Comment: Ma anche qui il senso è quello di "tradire" il luogo natio cedendolo per pochi soldi agli speculatori.

Comment: @ abarisone -        Sì, certo, la metafora è quella del tradimento o di danaro in cambio di qualcosa di spregevole. Qual è il  problema?

Comment: Potreste aggiungere qualcosa sul senso che ha questa espressione come frase fatta o modo di dire? Penso sia necessario per avere una risposta completa.

Comment: @Gio: Sì, ma penso che si debba aggiungere questa spiegazione alla risposta.

Comment: Aggiungerei anche la frase di Corto Maltese nella "Ballata del mare salato": "Hew! Hew! Siamo in piena inflazione... una volta non bastavano trenta denari?" O quella che il demonio rivolge a Dylan Dog in "Golconda": "E piantala di chiamare Giuda "ballerino"! Al giorno d'oggi con trenta denari c'è poco da andare a ballare! Bastano al massimo per un caffè!"

Answer (score 3):

L'espressione ***i trenta denari*** indica generalmente chi tradisce in cambio di denaro, facendo riferimento a Giuda Iscariota.

Da Treccani "[Le parole che usiamo: Trenta (denari)](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/atlante/societa/le_parole_che_usiamo_30_denari.html)"

> Si parla molto di Giuda, di questi tempi, forse non per caso. Dopo che
>   papa Benedetto XVI lo ha definito zelota, vale a dire un patriota del
>   tempo contro l’invasione romana, un partigiano della sua nazione, gli
>   specialisti si sono messi a discutere sulla realtà e il significato di
>   una figura controversa, ma che ha nella tradizione occidentale un
>   significato univoco: quello del traditore di una fede per denaro, con
>   il bacio perfido a suggellare il tradimento.

In tutte le accezioni che ho trovato fa riferimento sempre ad un tradimento:

> In certi abbracci senti distinto il tintinnare dei ***trenta denari***.
>
> Sono incline a credere che Giuda abbia depositato in banca i suoi
>   ***trenta denari***, lasciando gli interessi in eredità ai nostri traditori.

Dialogo dal film "Ricomincio da tre" di Massimo Troisi:

> Gianna: Ecco, ti pareva...
>
> Gaetano: No, no...
>
> Gianna: ..sempre davanti la televisione. [Gli spegna il televisore]
>
> Gaetano: ...no, aspetta, Gianna, famme vere' che fann.
>
> Gianna: Oooh! Ma cosa speri di vederci, Dio?
>
> Gaetano: Dio! Chell è o secondo canale chist..
>
> Gianna: Comunque quel film devo dire che era tremendo, a me mi ha
>   veramente... impaurito. Ma senti, se a te ti torturassero come a
>   quello del film, avresti parlato?
>
> Gaetano: Pe' carità! A me non c'era nemmeno bisogno che mi
>   torturavano: a me bastava che mi dicevano sulamente... per esempio...
>   "Guarda che se non parli... forse... ti torturiamo", immediatamente
>   parlavo, scrivevo, cioè se non capevano facevo nu disegno...
>
> Gianna: Eh, ma allora sei peggio di Giuda!
>
> Gaetano: No, che c'entra? È proprio che io, per esempio il dolore
>   fisico nun 'o supporto proprio. È na cosa ca... e po' che c'entra cioè
>   Giuda? Mo tutte quante "Giuda traditore", "Giuda traditore". Cioè
>   s'anna conosce prima e' fatt, eh? Giuda avrà avuto una ragione per
>   fare na' cosa del genere, no?
>
> Gianna: Eh no! Per soldi.
>
> Gaetano: Eh, per soldi, e non è una ragione, scusa? Basta che 'o
>   facevano nascere ricco e già s'evitava tutta st'ammuina, sta cosa...
>   l'uccisione, 'o tradimento e poi lasciamm sta', cioè pecchè.. quanno
>   uno non conosce a' gente nun me piace e' giudica', capit? Pecchè
>   miette... sa' tu hai bisogno proprie... A un certo punto, **sti trenta
>   denari**, quante putivanu essere, mettiamo due, trecentomila lire,
>   quattrocento, unno saccio però chillo avrà miso apposto e cose soje.
>   Miett ca iva a casa e a mugliera ogni vota "Giuda, tu devi andare a
>   lavorare. Giuda. 'o padrone 'e casa, 'a luce, l'acqua" per dire "'o
>   telefono.." A un certo punto, chillo tutte 'ste cose.."Tu non porti
>   cchiù e sord' a casa!", "Tu non porti cchiù e sord' a casa!", s'ha
>   visto e' trenta denari in mano e ha ditt "Ma che me ne 'mporta! mo me
>   miett a

Comment: Quasi dimenticavo di aggiungere che in Italiano trenta denari indica anche lo spessore della trama dei collant femminili

Comment: Vero, ma in che senso i produttori di calze  usano la parola "denari" in riferimento alla trama dei collant?

Comment: “Unità di misura (simbolo den) della finezza delle fibre naturali e sintetiche: un filato ha titolo di 1 den quando 9000 m di quel filo pesano 1 grammo. Oggi è per lo più sostituito dal tex (v.), spec. per i filati artificiali” ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/denaro))

Comment: Quanto ai “trenta denari” della domanda, sarebbe forse interessante trovare ulteriori citazioni in cui _non_ si parla di Giuda.

Comment: Trovo davvero curioso quello delle calze. Nel mio paese usiamo anche questa unità di misura, ma la chiamamo semplicemente *den*: non avevo idea che "den" fosse un'abbreviazione di "denaro".

Comment: Concordo con @DaG: sarebbe interessante trovare qualche esempio di uso che non faccia riferimento esplicito a Giuda.

Comment: Del "denaro" come unità di misura per lo spessore delle calze ne parla anche la [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denaro_(unit%C3%A0_di_misura)).

Comment: Ma penso che un conto è l'espressione o modo di dire "trenta denari" e un conto i vari significati che può avere la parola denari. Che tra l'altro indica anche un seme delle carte. A mia conoscenza trenta denari ha solo il riferimento biblico del tradimento di Giuda.

Comment: Hai ragione, @abarisone: è semplicemente che ho trovato molto curioso quello delle calze.